# Axis2 ADB Client via proxy?

Tags: web-services, proxy, apache-axis

I have created an adb client successfully for a web service from a third party supplier, and this is working well on our development environment.

Our live environment requires all internet access through a proxy

How can I add the proxy information to the Web service calls / setup ?

I have searched around but couldn't find any examples.

I have
- created stub from wsdl
- created accessor utility class which will instanciate the stub for me, from my web application
- created stand alone test client

overview of the test client.

```
EUserHistoryServiceStub stub =new EUserHistoryServiceStub(url);
GetUserHistory requestObj = new GetUserHistory();
//set values on requestObj
GetUserHistoryResponse res = stub.getUserHistory(requestObj);
//read the response.
```

Do I have to do anything different, when running test client / in web application ?

Any help would be great.

Many thanks

Mark

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the standard Java system properties (http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort) to configure the proxy or you can configure it in Axis2 as described [here](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/http-transport.html#auth).